# Gram-Schmidt procedure for new base, complete positivity

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite, gram-schmidt

Let say that $v_1,v_2,...v_n$ be vectors in a $m$-dimensional Euclidian space $V$. There exists a natural number $k$ and an isometry  $T:V \Rightarrow R^k$ such that $$Tv_1,Tv_2,..., Tv_n \in  R^k_+=\{x \in R^n|x_i \geq 0\text{ for }i=1,\dots,n\}.$$

This is true, if $Gram(v_1,v_2,...)$ is completely positive. Here $k$ is the number of columns of $B$ and for each $i=1,2,...,n$, $Tv_i$ is the $i$-th row of $B$.
Why the vectors can be embedded in a nonnegative orthant of some Euclidian space?
Which statement provide us existence of $T$? Is it monotonous?

I know that I can get new base by Gram-Schmidt procedure.

Please, I really need an explanation about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show that if $A := \operatorname{Gram}\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ is completely positive, then there exists a $k$ and an isometry $T$ such that $Tv_i \in \Bbb R^k_+$.

Let $P$ denote the matrix with columns $v_1,\dots,v_n$; note that $A = P^TP$.  Because $A$ is completely positive, there exists a matrix $B$ for which $B^TB = A$.  Let $b_1,\dots,b_n$ denote the columns of $B$. Let $V$ denote the span of $v_1,\dots,v_n$, and define the linear map $T:V \to \Bbb R^k$ by $T(v_k) = b_k$.

Because $P^TP = B^TB$, we have $v_i^Tv_j = b_i^Tb_j$. It now suffices to show the following:

**Claim:** $T$ is an isometry over $V$.

**Proof:** Any vector $v \in V$ can be written in the form
$$
v = c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_n v_n.
$$
We note that
$$
\begin{align}
\|T(v)\|^2 &= (T(v))^TT(v) = \left(T\sum_i c_i v_i\right)^T \left(T\sum_{j}c_j(v_i)\right)
\\ & = \sum_{i,j} c_ic_j T(v_i)^TT(v_j)
= \sum_{i,j} c_ic_j v_i^Tv_j
\\ & = \left(\sum_i c_i v_i\right)^T \left(\sum_{j}c_j(v_i)\right)
= \|v\|^2.
\end{align}
$$
So, $\|T(v)\| = \|v\|$, which is to say that $T$ is an isometry, as desired.

Comment: So if $A=Gram(v_1,...,v_n)$, than $A$ can be written as $A=BB^T$. When $A$ is completely positive, then $A$ have all the elements that are positive. So the widest angle is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ as $cos$ should be positive. Po we can find a $T$ that all $v_1,...v_n$ end up in positive orthant? Something like that?

Comment: @what_456 I'm not sure what you're saying after the first sentence. Because $A = BB^T$ for a matrix $B$ with non-negative entries, $A$ is [completely positive](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompletelyPositiveMatrix.html).

Comment: @what Your $A$ doesn't make sense. I thought $A$ was supposed to be a square matrix with $A = BB^T$

Comment: @what I see, I had the direction of implication wrong. I'll edit accodingly

Comment: Yes. I wanted to take a look on geometric approach on complete positivity. But I need to explain why there exist $T$ for complitely positive matrices that $Tv_1,Tv_2,... $ are in $R_k^+$. For example if $A=\begin{pmatrix} 2&3&2&3\\
3&5&3&5\\
2&3&2&3\\
3&5&3&5
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1\\
1&2\\
1&1\\
1&2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1\\
1&2&1&2
\end{pmatrix}$ then we know $Tv_1=[1,1]$ and $Tv_2=[1,2]$. What about isometries?

Comment: @what See my latest edit

Comment: why is this true? 
$ \sum_{i,j} c_ic_j T(v_i)^TT(v_j)
= \sum_{i,j} c_ic_j v_i^Tv_j
$

Comment: @what_456 For each $i,j,$ we have
$$
T(v_i)^TT(v_j) = b_i^T b_j = v_i^T v_j,
$$
as is established right before the claim.

Comment: Yes that is true. But what if $B$ is $k \times n$ and $P$ is $n \times n$, than $b_i^Tb_j=v_i^Tv_j$, but not in the sum because than you need to change for which $i$ and $j$ its true.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it if $B$ id $k \times n$ and $P$ is $n \times n$?

Comment: @what_456 I disagree with your first comment. I have no clue what you mean by "you need to change for which $i$ and $j$ its true."

Comment: I meant that if $B$ is $k \times n$ and $P$ is $n \times n$, than 
$\sum_{i,j} c_ic_j T(v_i)^TT(v_j)
= \sum_{i,j} c_ic_j v_i^Tv_j$ is not true due to my initial assumptions.

Comment: @w Ok, now I understand what you are saying but I have no idea why you believe that this is the case. If you believe that $v_i^T v_j= b_i^T b_j$ holds for every pair $i, j$, then there should be no issues with following the proof

Comment: Is it true that $V$ is span of $v_1,...,v_n$ as P is the same rank as A?